# Access denied to server in File System Linked Service in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service

I'm trying to create a File System Linked Service in Data Factory in order to access a folder (\\serverName\c$\folder) using Self-Hosted Integration Runtime, even though I inserted an user who has "Full Control" permission on this specific folder, when I test connection, it returns the following error message:

*Please consider I changed "serverName" with the proper server name, which is the same one I installed the IR.*

> The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Access to serverName is
> denied, resolved IP address is ::1, network type is OnPremise'. Access
> to serverName is denied, resolved IP address is ::1, network type is
> OnPremise

What really concerns me is that this message says the "property '' is invalid", how am I supposed to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had a similar issue: Accessing a (shared -> only read access) folder from an Azure VM on which I had installed the SHIR.

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions) you have to enable the access to the local machine for copying files on each SHIR node. To do this I opened the PowerShell on the VM and entered the following two commands (using IR version 5.0; for details to this command see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell)) to run the dmgcmd.exe:

```
 cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared\"
 .\dmgcmd.exe -EnableLocalMachineAccess
```

Comment: This would work, but you can do it without needing to change the path in the linked service, as well as allowing access to other local network paths by using `.\dmgcmd.exe -EnableLocalMachineAccess` instead. No changes are required in the linked service, you just need to run that command on each SHIR node. This was in the same documentation you referenced.

Comment: @DavidP comment should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [offical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell),  the latest SHIR has a security fix that has been changed and does not allow access to local files by default.

[image]

> To resolve the issue, you must run `.\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation` to disable the setting for more details, refer to [Set up an existing self-hosted IR via local PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell)

[image]

[image]

> **Default:** Enable security validation to disable access to file system of the local machine.

[image]

> After Disabling access to file system of the local machine using: `.\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation` able to access the data from linked service.

[image: Resolve]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue *The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Access to serverName is denied, resolved IP address is ::1, network type is OnPremise'*    After lot of investigation I noticed that Automatic update was enabled on Integration Runtime which caused this issue. updated latest integration runtime was pointing to IPv6 network traffic rather than IPv4 network traffic. I had to uninstall and re-install the older version of IR and disabled the auto-update feature on integration runtime from azure portal.

Answer (score -2):

> The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Access to serverName is denied, resolved IP address is ::1, network type is OnPremise'.

Looking at the error message. The Self-Hosted Integration Runtime cannot access the servername. multiple factors, including wrong permissions, connectivity problems on the network or configuration settings, might be causing for this.

To resolve this, you can try below solutions:

- Check to see if the user account you are using in linked service has the access on that particular folder/file. check if you are able to open it with particular user.
- Make that the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime is installed on a machine that can connect to the server. To validate, you can try pinging the server from the device with `ping servername` if you are getting `Ping request could not find host serverName. Please check the name and try again.` there might be connectivity issue with server.
- Make sure your servername username and password is correct.

Also, Check this [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/security-and-access-control-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#invalid-or-empty-authentication-key-issue-after-public-network-access-is-disabled) regarding connectivity errors in self-hosted integration runtime

If still issue persist you can raise a support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for more investigation.