# how to import files from Local system to azure sql using Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-file-share

i'm trying to import files from My local system to azure sql database using file system in azure data factory. but i'm not able to import files.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: what error you are facing and can you add your pipeline images?

Comment: When testing the linked service connection, is it successful? Otherwise are you getting the same error.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Linked service, getting this error

Comment: Which type of IR you ae using? Could you please provide those details?

Comment: IR with Managed Virtual Network & AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime, both i can try

Comment: Did you try with Self-Hosted IR?

Comment: No, i don't try Self -Hosted IR

Comment: Actuvally i have a Excel file on my local system, load the excel file to azure sql, i don't hav e storage account, thats why im  using file system as a source

Comment: If you want to copy files from local storage you should use Self-hosted IR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created with file system linked service with azure IR I got below error:

[image]

I Created self-hosted integration runtime.

[image]

installed self-hosted IR locally and register with generated access key.

[image]

Created file system linked service with required details:

[image]

Comment: im getting error is Host path error, error code 22853

Comment: Where you are getting that error, could you please provide the whole error?

Comment: Access to 'C:\Users\chinnu\Documents\Practice' is not allowed.
 Activity ID: 9d3211c5-f4d0-4abd-98d0-87ec9f715ced.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402958/azure-data-factory-linked-service-to-c-drive/76464638#76464638) once?

Comment: Cannot connect to 'C:\Users\Documents\Practice'. Detail Message: The system could not find the environment option that was entered The system could not find the environment option that was entered Activity ID: c70f06d0-3eac-416d-a609-b561769f4d5d.

Comment: Did you run the PowerShell script in your local?

Comment: yes.. completed

Comment: check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/396059/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-with-creating-adf-file).

Comment: Actually SHIR installed another system, but same azure data factory, can i load files from my local system to using that SHIR...its is possible to connect linked service