# How to load Azure VM local files to azure sql database using self-hosted IR?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-vm-role

I have an azure VM having csv files, i don't have storage account, so how to load VM local files into azure sql database using file system and self-hosted IR

Comment: Could you please provide your approach if any tried?

Comment: I have uploded file in my VM, and create linked service using file system in SHIR, where can i get my VM user id & password

Comment: Go to command prompt and execute whoami command you will get your username

Comment: where can i get password, how to create password?

Comment: It should be the password while creating vm.

Comment: SHIR installed in VM in private n/w, and files also loaded in same VM, can i create linked service without open VM in public n/w? it is possible?

Comment: Yes you can create.

Comment: how can i take Host path? and the files are loded in VM.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76506846/how-to-import-files-from-local-system-to-azure-sql-using-azure-data-factory/76507565#76507565) once.

Comment: use file system connector to load VM local files into azure SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your username of VM as follows:

Open command prompt and execute `whoami` command, you will get username as mentioned below:

[image]

Create a file system linked service using SHIR with username and VM password and path is in `\users\<filepath>\<filename>` as mentioned below:

[image]

For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76897244/how-to-load-azure-vm-local-files-to-azure-sql-database-using-self-hosted-ir).